# perl (syntax error) - Global symbol "@arr1" requires explicit package name

Tags: perl, syntax, error-handling

I'm getting error with a message "Global symbol "@arr1" requires explicit package name..".
I googled around, and I found out that I need to declare variable with "my".
But in my case, I don't understand why I'm getting erros for this arrays, as I have defined

```
my ($arr1, $arr2) = @_;
```

The error is pointing at:

```
$#arr1 = $nLen;
$#arr2 = $nLen;
```

Here is my code:

```
sub azip{
    my ($arr1, $arr2) = @_;

    if (@$arr1 != @$arr2) {
        print "Arrays \@$arr1 and \@$arr2 are not equal!\n";
        my $nLen; 
        if (@$arr1 > @$arr2) {
            $nLen = @$arr2 - 1;
            $#arr1 = $nLen;
        } 
        else {
            $nLen = @$arr1 - 1;
            $#arr2 = $nLen;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `$arr1` is array reference, you might try

```
$#$arr1 = $nLen; # or $#{ $arr1 }
```

and

```
$#$arr2 = $nLen;
```

Answer (score 2):

`arr1` is a scalar value, not an array; `$#arr` expects `@arr` to be defined. Assuming that `$arr1` does in fact contain a reference to an array, you can use

```
$#$arr1 = $nLen;
```